# NSURLConnection(download large files more than 500M)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to download a large file (> 500MB) to my application from the server. I used NSURLConnection, that works well if the network is  very good. but sometimes I tried to download 500MB file, but 200MB or 100MB only downloaded if the network is not very good.That means I got the connectionDidFinishLoading  method when the task was not completed.Someone says set a timeout second to avoid this situation，but i set  timeout  second 30s，it did not work.Should I set 60s or more？ Does someone have better idea,please help me.

Comment: So you're getting `connectionDidFinishLoading` before all the data has been downloaded? That sounds wrong. I'd expect to get an error if it's not downloaded all the data.

Comment: That indeed sounds wrong, can you post some test code? What do you mean by the network is not very good?

Comment: You should accept an answer if they are resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

in `connectionDidFinishLoading` method every time check the length of data to download and the downloaded data.

length of the data to be download is gain by this `[response expectedContentLength];` in `didReceiveResponse` method

Comment: You can't count on the expectedContentLength. It's kind of optional for a server to send it.

Answer (score 0):

You should download such big file in parts. Specify the Content-Range field in the header of your HTTP request and ask only for a small portion of the file at once. When you get all portions, you can assemble the file together.

You can set HTTP headers with `NSMutableURLRequest setValue:@"0-1023/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Range"];`, this example downloads only the first kbyte of the file. See also Content-Range in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Also, not all servers support Content-Range. I remember that rapidshare for example used to refuse partial downloads from non-paying users, because using Content-Range you can continue a download. With that type of servers you either download it all or you don't.

Comment: @fbernardo is right, you have to check whether your server supports this. I was somehow supposing that you have control over the server. If it doesn't support, there is not much to do except hoping that your file will arrive as a whole.

Comment: you're right, it does seem like he has control over the server, I was just suggesting that building portable code that works on more than one situation would be better...